# Aptana 3 SFTP Connection Issues with Business Catalyst

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'll preface this question by stating that at my day job we work with Adobe's Business Catalyst CMS, which is a self hosted CMS. Most of the people in my office use Dreamweaver for development, but I'm not a fan. I'd really like to use Aptana 3 as I'm really enjoying it so far. However, I'm having trouble setting up SFTP connections to any Business Catalyst sites. I've successfully connected to other hosting accounts with other providers just fine, but all Business Catalyst sites are giving me trouble.

When setting up a connection I'm using all of the exact same credentials that I've used with many other ftp clients. I've triple checked everything. However, I'm getting the following error when setting up an SFTP connection in Aptana:

> Establishing SFTP connection failed: The connection did not complete.

I contacted Business Catalyst support and they said that Aptana might not support Business Catalyst encryption. I'm kind of at a loss here. I'm wondering if there's an extra step I can take in order to solve this problem. I'd be eternally grateful for any assistance offered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I talked between Adobe Business Catalyst support and Aptana's main developer about this exact issue several months ago. There was a key that needed to be implemented into Aptana for them to communicate with BC's SFTP. The Aptana developer has this info, but at this has not been implemented as of yet. You will not be able to use Aptana to connect to BC with SFTP as of this time.